# What mechanism allows ViM to temporarily overwrite the entire console?

Tags: vim, ncurses, tty

When you enter [vim](http://www.vim.org/), it "clears" the screen. Upon exiting, it "restores" the original contents.

I understand one can use `\x1b[2J` to clear the console and reset the cursor position, but this will overwrite terminal contents.

I assume Vim uses [ncurses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses) under the hood, in which case I suppose the better question is how ncurses does this, but how is it done?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Most terminal emulators are able to save and restore the contents of the screen.

The terminfo codes for this are `smcup` to enter full-screen mode and `rmcup` to leave it. (The older termcap codes are `ti` and `te`.)

If these capabilities are enabled in the `terminfo` database, any program that uses `ncurses` will print the `smcup` string on entry, and the `rmcup` string on exit.

On the system I'm using at the moment, the strings are (with `\E` representing the Escape character):

```
smcup: \E7\E[?1;47h
rmcup: \E[2J\E[?1;47l\E8
```

This restores the previous contents of the screen as well as the cursor position.

The specific meanings of the sequences (for xterm) are [documented here](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html):

- smcup:

  - `\E7` Save Cursor
  - `\E[?1;47h` Application Cursor Keys; Use Alternate Screen Buffer
- rmcup:

  - `\E[2J` Erase screen
  - `\E[?1;47l` Application Cursor Keys; Use Normal Screen Buffer
  - `\E8` Restore Cursor

(This assumes I'm understanding the use of the semicolon correctly; I'm not 100% sure of that.)

Comment: Learned something new. This explains a lot; thank you.

Comment: Setting application cursor-keys normally is not done in smcup/rmcup - most programs assume it is done in the initialization string (is2).  See for example [putty](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-putty) in the ncurses terminal database.  And of course, mode 47 has long been obsolete with xterm (since [1998](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.log.html#xterm_90)).

Comment: @ThomasDickey: Apparently my termcap/terminfo entries are out of date (which is not surprising). Thanks for the information. I'll do some research and update my answer Real Soon Now.

Comment: Try it with `echo -e '\E7\E[?1;47h'` and `echo -e '\E[2J\E[?1;47l\E8'`

Answer (score 11):

Regarding the answer by [@Keith Thompson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/827263/keith-thompson) — not exactly:

- vim does not use the screen optimization of ncurses which sends `smcup` and `rmcup` automatically.  Rather, it is a [termcap application](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#uses_of_library). It *follows* a convention used by most (not all) termcap applications.  There are some implementations of `vi` which do not for instance (on IRIX64 perhaps).
- as for "most terminals" — actually, xterm look-alikes are a small part of the [terminal database](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src-sections.html) (even counting variations, less than 10%).  Rephrase that to something like "the most common terminal emulators on Linux.
- the terminal does not *save* and *restore* the screen contents.  Instead, it switches *between* two screens (in xterm's documentation "normal" and "alternate").  In xterm for instance, one can always switch between the two using a menu entry.  The xterm FAQ *[Why doesn't the screen clear when running vi?](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#xterm_tite)* gives more detail.
- for better context, note that [`smcup`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/terminfo.5.html) is an (obscure) abbreviation for *set-mode-cursor-positioning*, or *start cursor-positioning mode*. (also *cursor-addressing*).  The `r` in `rmcup` means "reset" (and `m` means "mode"). set/reset have different connotations from save/restore; with the latter the user is led to believe that the values can be stacked up.