# How to Not Overwrite Previous Terminal Contents

Tags: android, linux, shell, pagination, git-bash

I'm not sure if this is a duplicate, but I have no clue what to search for if it is, as I don't know the name for this phenomenon.

Basically, whenever I use `vim` and `less` on certain computers, the previous terminal contents are overwritten by the buffer of the current file (I think). If I scroll back with the scrollbar, rather than the current program's commands, I can see the previous terminal contents, but some of the previous lines have been written over by the current program. It seems like however many lines went through the buffer (I think) of, for example, `vim`, is how many previous lines of the terminal were overwritten. When I quit out of `vim`/`less`, those lines were still overwritten, though they show up in the history and when I press `up` to go "back" through the history.

However, on other computers, something quite different happens. While I am using `vim` or `less`, if I scroll up and down, I cannot see the previous lines of the terminal. In fact, on most computers where this phenomenon occurs, if I scroll back with the mouse, `vim` and `less` scroll back through the file in the current buffer, as if I pressed `Ctrl-E`/`Ctrl-Y`. When I quit `vim`/`less`, I do not see the file at all, I only see the previous contents of the terminal, as in whatever I was doing before I opened the file.

Whenever I use `more`, no matter what computer I use, the former phenomenon occurs, but I don't use `more` that much, as I like `less` better in every way, so I haven't tested its limits.

The computers/virtual terminals where I experienced the former phenomenon seem to be older computers and/or computers with lesser capabilities and specs, which makes sense as most people would probably want the latter, but it is probably harder to accomplish and requires more processing power and memory.

The computers with the former experience were: 2 old `RedHat`'s at my work, that are probably from the late 2000's/early 2010's, which I accessed from a `Windows 7` computer with `Penguinet`; `Android` phones/tablets with the Terminal Rex IDE where I "install the system". On most `Android` terminal apps, I can not get `vim`, `less`, or even `vi`, though I get `more`. When I used `vagrant` with `Git Bash`, with the default `TERM` value of `msys`, the terminal was all messed up, and I experienced most of the same behavior, but worse. When I changed `TERM` to `cygwin` or `xterm`, it was better.

The computers with the more desired behavior (for me) were: my newest laptop with `Ubuntu 15.04` (yes, a cmputer with `Linux` preinstalled); any Linux VM I installed on my Windows 8 laptop in the past couple years, but I only got the newest versions so I don't know how old the behavior is; `Git Bash` on my Windows 8 laptop. `Git Bash` did not scroll back through the file when I scrolled with the mouse, but rather through an empty terminal, but that may have been because of settings in my `vimrc`/`lessrc`. When I quit in `Git Bash`, it still showed me all the previous lines and not the file.

Most of these computers were using `bash`, but I still experienced the newer phenomenon when I installed and used `fish` on my newest `ubuntu` computer, even when I made it the default shell, and I don't believe `Git Bash` is technically `bash`, though it could be. I believe the `Terminal Rex` app used `bash` when it installed to the system, but when I check the `SHELL` environment variable with other terminal apps, and with Terminal Rex without the system installed, it reports as `sh`.

I am interested in why these behaviors occur, but I am *more* interested in a way to change it to the more desired behavior. **Is there a way to make the behavior of `vim` & `less` on older/less capable computers be more like the behaviors on newer ones?** Also, is there a way to make `Git Bash` scroll back through the file rather than the blank terminal?

**Bonus**: Is there a way to make `more` behave more like `less` on the newer computers? Or is this just the difference between `more` and `less`? Come to think of it, is it possible that the `less` on the less capable computers is actually `more`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The behavior being described is the xterm-style *alternate screen*.  There are two cases:

- when it *is* used, the terminal switches to the *alternate* screen when you run full-screen programs such as vim.
- when *not* used, the terminal continues in the *normal* screen when running full-screen programs.

The normal/alternate screens are the same size: the visible portion of the terminal *ignoring* the scrollback area.  You can see the scrollback using a mouse.  If you do that while switched to the alternate screen, you can see the scrollback adjacent to the current (alternate) screen.  After switching back, e.g., when vim exits, the previous lines are shown throughout the scrollback and current (normal) screen.  There is no marker between the two.

Some aspects of the normal/alternate screen were recently discussed in *[What mechanism allows ViM to temporarily overwrite the entire console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31575382/what-mechanism-allows-vim-to-temporarily-overwrite-the-entire-console/31575823#31575823)*

Most applications on Unix (and Linux and BSD and ...) pay attention to the `TERM` environment variable, which they (or a library such as [ncurses](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.html)) uses to retrieve information from the [terminal database](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.html#download_database).  In principle, one can set `TERM` separately for different applications to elicit different behavior (with the caveat that some applications such as vim have built-in tables to "fix" the terminal database which they may apply without warning). For example, running in a POSIX shell (or something like bash), you could type this to run vim and less with two different terminal descriptions:

```
TERM=vt100 vim foo.c
TERM=xterm less foo.c
```

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to implement the solutions in your link. I found a resource that is easier to understand and implement, though I probably wouldn't have found it without your help: http://www.shallowsky.com/linux/noaltscreen.html. The `vim` and `less` solutions worked for me, though you need to add them before you open the file and before you start the shell, respectively, which seems like a drag. If you want one of the 2 behaviors all the time, however, like me, it should be fine. I'm not sure where to go to implement the X ones, and whether it'll be worth it.