# Why the linux manpages program does not erase terminal

Tags: linux, terminal, ansi-escape, termcap

How does the man program manage to restore previous terminal output after taking over the entire screen? Does it involve ANSI escape sequences in a way?

Comment: you can always get the source for `man` and see what it's doing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the ubiquitous xterm alternate-screen feature, which most terminal programs use via the terminfo `smcup` and `rmcup` sequences.  For recent comments on this feature:

- *[How to Not Overwrite Previous Terminal Contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31628932/how-to-not-overwrite-previous-terminal-contents/31630250#31630250)*
- *[What mechanism allows ViM to temporarily overwrite the entire console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31575382/what-mechanism-allows-vim-to-temporarily-overwrite-the-entire-console/31575823#31575823)*

(By the way, the `man` program is usually a ["termcap" program](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#uses_of_library)).

Comment: Heh. I use a custom terminfo entry with empty `smcup`/`rmcup` fields just so I can stop programs from switching to an alternate screen. I hate it when I quit, say, `less` and the whole text I was looking at is just gone.